# is it possible adding exec-shiled into an arm based embedded linux platform

Tags: security, linux-kernel, arm, embedded-linux, buffer-overflow

I want to use Red hat's exec-shield project in my embedded linux platform. My linux version is 3.14.28-1.6. I wonder if it is possible or not. Is there an equivalent or similar way of doing this with gcc, controlling XN bit or something else?
Regards

Comment: What do you put in "exec-shield", what exactly do you want to do? If you talk about NX bit protection I'am sure mainline kernel uses it for a long time already.

Comment: i have a specification to satisfy. It says kernel of the system must include exec-shield and randomization features for hardening.